# subscription operation with webhook service in .net core mvc

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, webhooks, payment

I want to set up a subscription system with iyzico. I want to extend the subscription of the user whose payment was received after the response returned via webhook in the database. How do I do this with .net core mvc

What I want to do is actually use iyzico's webhook service and process the successful payment result in our own project. Extend that member's subscription period.

```
`[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult HandleWebhook([FromBody] dynamic payload)
        {
                
            try
            {
                var req = new CreateThreedsPaymentRequest();
                req.Locale = Locale.TR.ToString();
                req.ConversationId = payload.paymentConversationId.GetString();
                req.PaymentId = payload.paymentId.GetString();
                //req.ConversationData = payload.conversationData;

                var options = new Options
                {
                    ApiKey = "4g9n1lKKfOSgUXv4E36N2eLBVsDu73GZ",
                    SecretKey = "mPk5aTnFDUTsN9zvwlSRNp8wcnQmec9A",
                    BaseUrl = "https://api.iyzipay.com/"
                };

                var threedsPayment = ThreedsPayment.Create(req, options);

                if (threedsPayment.Status == "success")
                {
                    var paymentId = threedsPayment.PaymentId;
                    var plan = db.Plans.Where(x => x.Id.ToString() == threedsPayment.PaymentItems[0].ItemId).FirstOrDefault();
                    var IsUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    IsUser.SubscriptionExpiration = Convert.ToDateTime((IsUser.SubscriptionExpiration > DateTime.Now)
                                    ? IsUser.SubscriptionExpiration.Value.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(plan.Month)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                    : DateTime.Now.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(plan.Month)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    IsUser.İsTrial = false;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    // Fatura bilgilerini işleme
                    var existingBill = db.Bills.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.PaymentId == paymentId);
                    if (existingBill == null)
                    {
                        Bills bill = new Bills
                        {
                            Amount = threedsPayment.PaidPrice,
                            BillNo = threedsPayment.BasketId,
                            PaymentId = paymentId,
                            UserId = IsUser.Id,
                            DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(IsUser.SubscriptionExpiration),
                            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now

                        };
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // Şu anki dizini alır
                        string failedUsersFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "repeationSubscribeLog.txt");

                        string userData = $"başarılı | {User.Identity.Name} | {threedsPayment.PaymentItems[0].ItemId} | {payload} " + Environment.NewLine; // Kullanıcı adı ve soyadını al

                        // Dosyaya yazma işlemi
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(failedUsersFilePath, append: true))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(userData);
                        }

                        return Ok();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // Şu anki dizini alır
                    string failedUsersFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "repeationSubscribeLog.txt");

                    //string failedUsersFilePath = @"C:\Users\Nesibe\Desktop\repeationSubscribeLog.txt";

                    string userData = $"başarısız threadpayment error | {User.Identity.Name} | {threedsPayment.ErrorMessage} | {payload}" + Environment.NewLine; // Kullanıcı adı ve soyadını al

                    // Dosyaya yazma işlemi
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(failedUsersFilePath, append: true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(userData);
                    }

                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // Şu anki dizini alır
                string failedUsersFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "repeationSubscribeLog.txt");

                string userData = $"başarısız kodlarda hata var |{User.Identity.Name} |{ex} |{payload}" + Environment.NewLine; // Kullanıcı adı ve soyadını al

                // Dosyaya yazma işlemi
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(failedUsersFilePath, append: true))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(userData);
                }
                throw ex;
            }
            return Ok();
        }`
```